# In Python, will memory for variables in a recursive function be freed if they're not used after the recursive call?

Tags: python, recursion

Below is some code written iteratively with mild resemblance to the DBSCAN algorithm:

```
rw = 100
for r in range(rw):
    neighs = retrieve_neighs(r)
    # rest of body
```

If I rewrite it using recursion, I might write:

```
rw = 100
def foo(r):
    if r < rw:
        neighs = retrieve_neighs(r)
        # rest of body
        foo(r + 1)
foo(0)
```

I expect retrieve_neighs to return a list (or some collection) of points - this opens up the possibility that an entire file of data could be loaded, right? Is there any recognition that neighs is not used after

```
foo(r + 1)
```

and so the memory neighs refers to is freed?

Comment: You can delete your `neighs` object once you are done with performing some operation on it. And if your are returning a list then you can create a generator object instead of whole list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're describing is a major effect of tail call optimization, which Python explicitly doesn't do because Guido feels that it [isn't worth the tradeoffs](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com.au/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html?m=1), especially in terms of debugging information. If the recursive version of the algorithm is clearer, you might consider explicitly doing `del neighs` once you no longer need it - this has the save effect as the variable falling out of scope, potentially making it eligible for garbage collection.